# AWS Amplify Setup Manually With Cognito Authentication And S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I get around the CloudFormation setup for AWS-Amplify for Angular?

The [AWS-Amplify Developer Guide](https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/angular_guide) includes a section on setting up Angular.  It would be great but it uses CloudFormation to setup up on AWS.  I guess this is OK if the user doesn't have an existing setup.

However, the CF setup selects the region where Cognito is setup.  In my case this is Oregon.  But my ec2 stack, S3, and Postgres is already setup on Norcal.  Cognito isn't in Norcal yet so I'm stuck with Oregon and will move it when it is available here.  So the CF setup just creates a mess in my AWS account and in my Angular files.  I have a lot of deleting to do.

What is needed is a manual setup.  The only blog post that seems to cover this is on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1246180/Using-Open-Source-AWS-Amplify-JS-with-Cognito-Host) but I'm not sure if it is up-to-date.  Amplify seems to be changing fast.  I'm finding it difficult to reconcile the official docs with this post, but that may be due to ignorance.  I've never setup authentication before.

Any thoughts on a solution for replacing the CloudFront part of the setup?  The rest is easy enough.

Comment: Why not just read the CF template and do the necessary bits by hand?

Comment: I've tried that.  Also ran amplify init and the others in terminal and then tried to hack the resulting aws-export.js file.  Still working on that but no luck so far.  It shouldn't be this difficult.